# How to avoid the unbounded local error to create the big string?

Tags: python

I want to concatenate to get a big string:

```
big_str = ''
def create_big_str():
    with open('big.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line:
                continue

            big_str = big_str + ' ' + line
```

then in other places, i want to use the 'big_str' variable. But it reports the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable
```

at the line:

```
big_str = big_str + ' ' + line
```

Add the 'global' doesn't help either.

Comment: After ```def create_big_str():``` put in one line: ```global big_str```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass big_str to the function in the declaration statement:

```
def create_big_str(big_str):
```

Comment: How is this different from the global keyword way?

Comment: You would be creating a local variable inside the function (above I called it 'big_str', but you can call it 'x' or something different, which is preferred). The function should return the final string and you can then assign to another variable or 'big_str'.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change a global variable from inside a function, you explicitly have to declare that you intend to do that:

```py
big_str = ''
def create_big_str():
    global big_str  # note this line
    with open('big.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line:
                continue

            big_str = big_str + ' ' + line
```